# switching off finger debugging infos in android

Tags: debug

My Android phone (sony z3, running 4.4.4) keeps showing finger tracks as well as the finger tracking debugging infos. How can I turn that off?

The feature got accidentally turned on (for me unaware) while the phone was in my pocket.

a screen image is attached[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These features are part of Developer Options.

Settings > Developer Options > Input

Turn off Show touches

Turn off Show pointer location.

This terminology is from my Samsung S3, yours may be similar.

This is deep into the settings heirarchy, it is unlikely accidental.